# Disable Url Edit on browser Android

Tags: android

With the following code I can start an activity to open the url in an external browser.
But I am after opening not the user to allow to edit the url once it's being opened in the browser.

I've seen this feature on some of the apps.

```
  private final  static String URL = "https://medium.com";
  Uri uri= Uri.parse(URL);
  Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);


  if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Comment: "I've seen this feature on some of the apps" -- name some.

Comment: I've seen this on Udacity app

Comment: How did you determine that Udacity is launching the user's choice of Web browser, and is then somehow preventing that browser from showing an address bar, rather than using `WebView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chrome Custom Tabs instead of Implicit Intents that opens phone's default browser. Chrome Custom Tabs allows you to open URL right in the app with UI customizations and event handling. Read more here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs